# Visualization of Homotopy equivalence between "heart curve" and zero

Tags: animation, visualization, topology

It is well-known that a "heart" is topologically equivalent to a "zero".

[image: heart and zero]

where $$(x^2+y^2-1)^3=x^2y^3$$ is the heart equation; and $$\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{3}=1$$ is the equation of the zero shape (an ellipse).

How do I animate a homotopy from the heart to zero?

Answer (score 13):

Here is a simple-minded smooth homotopy between the two curves in the OP, using a Hermite interpolant for keyframing:

```
hcubic[t_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[{{{0}, 0, 0}, {{1}, 1, 0}}, t];

Animate[ContourPlot[(1 - hcubic[t]) ((x^2 + y^2 - 1)^3 - x^2 y^3) +
                    hcubic[t] (x^2/2 + y^2/3 - 1) == 0,
                    {x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, -7/4, 7/4},
                    ContourStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[4],
                    Blend[{ColorData[61, 8], ColorData[61, 7]}, t]]],
        {t, 0, 1, 1/30}]
```

[image: heart to ellipse]

Answer (score 10):

Code from years ago, adapted for `Manipulate`, for a pre-calculus course:
Move `m` to see the homotopy.  (I used it at the end of the function-graph transformations to show "translating by a function" instead of by a constant.)  The other parameters were for finding a good-looking shape for class.  You can adapt or add coefficients for the desired "zero."

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[-((y - m (x^2)^(1/3))^2 + x^2 - a^2) == l,
  {x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a + 1}, PlotPoints -> 101, 
  ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[#/2 + 0.5, #^4, #^4] &), Axes -> False, 
  Frame -> False],
 {m, 0, 1},
 {{a, 2}, 0, 4},
 {{l, 0}, -5, 5}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]