# Lofting: Make a 3D surface out of two 2D end curves

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have 2D plot:

```
p1 =ParametricPlot[{Sin[x],Cos[x]},{x,0,2*Pi}]
```

[image]

and another 2D plot:

```
p2=ParametricPlot[{(5-0.2*x)*Sin[x],Cos[x]},{x,0,2*Pi}]
```

[image]

and I want to make a 3D object out of that. It would have to merge from the front, which is p1 to the back, which is p2. How can I do it ? Thank you.

Comment: Something like a cylinder, but with different ends?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, exactly. I give the two ends and Mathematica interpolates the surface between.

Comment: For reference: this operation is sometimes called *lofting*.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ParametricPlot3D` might help.

Defining your two 'end' functions:

```
f1[u_] := {Sin[u], Cos[u]}
f2[u_] := {(5 - 0.2 u) Sin[u], Cos[u]}
```

Then simply interpolate between the two as a function of length:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 Append[v f1[u] + (1 - v) f2[u], v], {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
]
```

[image]

Comment: One might also consider using a Hermite cubic instead of a linear function, as in [this example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97756). [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0aiNc.png) is what you get.

Comment: That's very nice!!

Comment: @Quantum_oli Thank you very much! :) :)

Comment: @Quantum_Oil can you try that: r[t_] := a + 1/b*Tanh[b*Sin[n*t]]              f1[t_] := 10*{r[t]*Cos[t], r[t]*Sin[t]}
f2[t_] := {r[t]*Cos[t], r[t]*Sin[t]}
(*Then simply interpolate between the two as a function of length:*)
ParametricPlot3D[
 Append[v f1[u] + (1 - v) f2[u], v], {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 Mesh -> 80, MeshFunctions -> Automatic]

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: Your `2[Pi]` should be a `2\[Pi]`.